# page layout url is messed up but unable to edit

Tags: page-layout

The following line needs to be change in the aspx pages in the pages library.
http://intranet.old.com/sales/_catalogs/masterpage/BlankWebPartPage.aspx, Blank Web Part Page

The new url should be intranet.new.com/sites/sales ...

I checked out the file, then open the pages library in windows explorer edit the document but my changes are not being made. The SP 2013 designer doesnt even open the page, only option it gives me is open it in browser or fix the page layout.

I tried a powershell from here https://nkelkar.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/post-migration-this-page-is-not-using-a-valid-page-layout/ but it did not change the url value.

I downloaded one of the page file from pages library and fixed the url, uploaded to the pages library, checked in. But all the webparts on that page is gone.

What else can I do to fix this issue?

May be I did not put the correct url in the powershell script?

Comment: I was able to run the Powershell script but now all the contents are gone (I mean various web parts on the pages are gone). What to do? Please advise.

Comment: Updates: It looks like the powershell script ran and most of the page layout url's got fixed except one of the page. I am copying the page using metalogix content matrix with all versions and web parts. I will re-run the PS script and see how the page looks like.